# For loop equivalent for einsum expression

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have the following Einstein Sum (einsum) expression,

```
import numpy as np 

x = np.random.rand(1,8,2,8,10)
y = np.random.rand(8,10,10)
z = np.einsum('nkctv,kvw->nctw', x, y)

print (z.shape)
```

The output is:

```
(1, 2, 8, 10)
```

What I'm trying to do is to built the equivalent functionality using a set of nested for loops, I followed this [tutorial](https://obilaniu6266h16.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/einstein-summation-in-numpy/) which shows how to implement some of einsum expression with nested for loops, but it didn't help that much.

Any one knows how to do it?

Comment: You need 6 loops, one per letter.   `k` and `v` are summed, and thus don't appear in the result.  The others just carry through from their inputs to the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @hpaulj,

The solution is:

```
R = np.zeros((1,2,8,13))

for n in range(1):
        for c in range(2):
            for t in range(8):
                for w in range(13):
                    total = 0
                    # These are the variables to sum over
                    for v in range(13):
                        for k in range(8):
                            total += x[n,k,c,t,v]*y[k,v,w]
                    R[n,c,t,w] = total
```